# React - Refreshing Save Counter

Tags: reactjs, redux, refresh, counter

I have a component and it's work well

Ok, in constructor I have:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    }
```

I have also function:

```
onClick(e) {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
    });
}
```

How make **count** not everytime **0**, but updating after refreshing?

Comment: updating after refreshing => means page refreshing ?

Comment: What do you mean after refreshing? You mean refreshing browser?

Comment: I want this values to persist after page reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example to increase the counter and reset the counter.
If you want this values to persist even after a page reload you cannot keep the value in the state. Not sure if you are looking for this only

```javascript
class TestJs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.resetCounter = this.resetCounter.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    }

    resetCounter(){
        this.setState({count : 0});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Counter value is {this.state.count}
                <br/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}> Increase counter</button>
                <br/>
                <button onClick={this.resetCounter}> Reset counter</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestJs
```

Comment: Ok, thank you.

So, when I can't use state, what I should to do?

Comment: You Can make use of the redux store of to store and retrieve it later.

An alternative, You can try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-localstorage local storage. This work well. I've used it.